# Check if array is empty

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

The following code shows an array of records in the `$rows` array from the MySQL query. I have added also an `if` statement to check if `$rows` turns up empty, but it is not working.

```
$rows = array();

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TestPhase where Pid<10", $db) or die("cannot select");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  $rows []= array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'parent' => $row['parent'],
    'name' => $row['name'],
  );

}


if($rows == ""){
    echo "No Data";

    }
```

This `if` statement is not working. How do I check if the array returns empty and echo "No Data".

How would I check to see if the array is empty in javascript? I have placed the `$rows` array in a `var treeData`.

```
if (treeData) is empty{
$("button").hide();
     }
```

How do I check if `treeData` is empty to hide the button.

Comment: How did you place the data from php into javascript? With json or from php?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**PHP**
Simply use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), i.e.

```
if(empty($rows)){
    echo 'No Data';
}
```

Alternatively you could also use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), i.e.

```
if(count($rows) < 1){ // or if(count($rows) === 0)
    echo 'No Data';
}
```

**JavaScript**
You can use the `length` property

```
if(treeData.length == 0){
    $("button").hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great. But please see the updated question. How do I do this in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Use `count` to check

```
if(!count($rows)){
    echo "No Data";
}
```

Using JavaScript, here is the example

```
var arr = new Array('one', 'two', 'three'); //assume you have list of values in array
if(!arr.length){ //if no array value exist, show alert()
   alert('No Data');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't treat an array like a string (i.e. `$rows == ""`). Use `count()` or `empty()` instead:

```
if(count($rows) == 0)
{
    echo "No Data";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
if( empty( $rows) ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( count( $rows ) == 0 ) {...}
```